# What could be a proper and simple invalid WKT/WKB geometry?

Tags: postgis, well-known-text, well-known-binary

We are converting a geometry table to another one and we would like to convert every invalid geometry to a single one easily identifiable by users in WKB or WKT form and not breaking the processing or display.

What could it be?

We do not want to use 'POLYGON EMPTY' because it could be something that exists in the original table. It could also be the result of some geoprocessing done on the converted table and then these ones would not be distinguiable from the original invalid ones...

Any better idea?

Comment: POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))

Comment: Null might be a better choice, or an infinite box. Depends on the end use of the table

Comment: There are an infinite number of invalid geometries. Changing them to a single form would prevent repair.

Comment: @Vince That's for the ones that ST_MakeValid() is unable to repair...

Comment: I recommend to use a separate table denoting the validity (and meta info about the cause or preferred action etc ) or even the invalid rows themselves, or use `NULL` *if absolutely necessary* (they are filtered out extremely performant with `NULLS FIRST/LAST` index declaration). You are going to produce data inconsistencies your way, why not repair?

Comment: How about a point or polygon placed somewhat outside the area where you can have real data? Then you could find all invalid cases with a simple spatial query or by selecting from the QGIS map view. And you could drop them out from further processing with a spatial filter as well.